# What facebook permissions do I need if my app is using the share plugin?

Tags: android, facebook

I submitted my app for facebook review (publish_actions) and they come back to me with the following:

"Your app is using the Share plugin to share content to Facebook, so you don't need to submit for review. Publish_actions is only for posting through the Graph API. See our sharing docs for more info on plugins."

And they direct me to this page: 
[Android Sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

However in that page it does not really tell me what permission I need to add in order for the app review process to be successful. At the moment my app just has the default permissions: email, public_profile and user_friends.

I am not sure what they really mean by "so you don't need to submit for review" Don't all the apps need to be reviewed? But to be reviewed, I need to add a permission and I do not know which one???? At the moment with the administrator login I can share a post fine but it does not work for any other user.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Facebook doesn't review apps. They review permissions. Only if you need extra permission you need to submit to get them. If you don't need extra permissions you can't submit. If you want other people to be able to use your app just take it live.

Comment: Yes I took it live and It works for the administrator or any tester user but it does not work for anybody else. i.e. if I remove the tester user from the tester user list it will not work for him/her anymore.

Comment: And what exactly does "does not work" mean?

Comment: Good point, Cbroe. It allows me to login, it does nothing for a couple seconds and then I get a message: sharing cancelled. However when I use a tester user the sharing is succesful.

Comment: Finally I found what the issue was. It was caused by using two different testing users in the same mobile phone. For whatever reason it just worked for the first one I login with and any other user won't work. However now I have a different issue. I am able to share the facebook dialog but just once.After that it will not work it will show the "share cancelled" error. So I can fix it by going on my mobile phone to settings->apps->click on my app and press "clear data". Once I do that I can go to the app and the facebook sharing will work just once again. Just once.

Comment: Im running some logs and the error I see is: "GameHelperUnable to show the provided content via the web or the installed version of the Facebook app. Some dialogs are only supported starting API 14. dialog error" but that does not make any sense cause I am using API 19